# how to create a mysql index without creating a table

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am using a graph database neo4j for storing data. I need three values from neo4j for every node and index into mysql.

The three values will be integers or long type and there will be millions of sets of these 3 numbers.
As far as I understand, in mysql, we need to create a table and then index its columns.

here lets say, i create a table "test" and int1, int2 & int3 as column names, then I can index these columns.

The problem is:- this increases unnecessary memory requirement, memory taken by both table and index.

Is there a way to create indexes in mysql, without creating a table?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. How are you going to access the data in mysql if there's no table?

Comment: No, there is not. An index is there to search in table data. No data, no index.

Comment: I was earlier indexing the data in elasticsearch, where we just need to index data not create a table/nodes. It indexes the data as json.
I was hoping if mysql has such feature.

Comment: Json is a very space-inefficient format (though not as bad as XML). The combined table and index data in MySQL is probably smaller than the same data in Json format. Interesting question, though.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken MySQL's table data "lives" in the clustered index of the primary key. So if you can make the three columns unique, you'd have what you are looking for. But again: I'm not sure. You will need to check the MySQL manual (in Oracle there is actually a special table type for this kind of structure: an index organized table)

Comment: @GloezTroi.... once i make table and indexes in mysql, i'll have a better idea about the size comaprison b/w mysql and elasticsearch json.